# How do I tell why my UIViewController is disappearing?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller

My `UIViewController` is in a navigation stack. How can I detect when the user is trying to pop up to a previous level vs. pushing a new view controller over it?

I want to post a notification when the view is removed from the stack, as if the user had tapped a **Save** button that I don't have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something in [`viewWillDisappear:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006926-CH3-SW18) and there is also the [UINavigationControllerDelegate protocol](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationControllerDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) that has two methods for detecting when views will or have been shown.

Comment: That won't work, it disappears if you pop it off or push something on top of it.

Comment: UINavigationControllerDelegate protocol looks the right way to go.

Comment: Agreed that `viewWillDisappear` would be a less than ideal place to do this as it can be called at times that do not make sense to your context. Though you could review the navigation stack within `viewWillDisappear` to see where in the hierarchy your view is located and do the appropriate thing. I think the UINaviationControllerDelegate is a better approach though.

Comment: This is looking like it will probably work in `navigationController:didShowViewController`: `id viewControllerStack = [navigationController viewControllers]; if ( [viewControllerStack count] == [_navigationStack count] - 1 ) { ... } _navigationStack = viewControllerStack;` Similar in `willShow`, only don't set `_navigationStack`. Gyrations are necessary because `viewControllers` is already updated by the time the delegate is called.

Comment: As a notice, `UINavigationControllerDelegate` doesn't tell you which view controller willHide/didHide. When a new view controller willShow/didShow, the willHide/didHide view controller may already been removed from `navigationController.viewControllers`.

Answer (score 3):

If you're using a `UINavigationController`, then [`UINavigationBarDelegate`](http://developer.apple.com/library/IOs/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationBarDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html) is the delegate class and it implements the following methods.

Pushing Items

```
– navigationBar:shouldPushItem:
– navigationBar:didPushItem:
```

Popping Items

```
– navigationBar:shouldPopItem:
– navigationBar:didPopItem:
```

You can put code in these method that you want to be executed when the view is popped from the stack.

Comment: This looks promising, thanks. (I'll accept once I get a chance to verify.)

Comment: Looks like a good idea, but doesn't work. Assigning a delegate to the UINavigationBar breaks the navigation controller. I guess that's how UINavigationBar interacts with UINavigationController.

Comment: @StevenFisher Curious; I managed to get this to work on an app a while back. I'll look for the project and post details. Until then, I found [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6413595/uinavigationcontroller-and-uinavigationbardelegate-shouldpopitem-with-monotouc?answertab=votes) which may help you.

Comment: The docs for UINavigationBar do indeed say the following: "A navigation controller automatically assigns itself as the delegate of its navigation bar object. Therefore, when using a navigation controller, you must not attempt to assign a custom delegate object to the corresponding navigation bar." But I wonder if you could put your own delegate in the middle and forward the calls to the navigation controller.