# UINavigationController Broken in IOS 8?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uinavigationcontroller, ios8

I have a series of UIViewControllers in my app, and these are presented using a UINavigationController. The HOME ViewController calls pushViewController to get to the PROFILES ViewController. The PROFILES screen correctly shows the back button to HOME. Then selecting a button on PROFILES will take the user to the DETAIL ViewController. The DETAIL screen correctly shows the back button to PROFILES. But when I press the back button to PROFILES, I do indeed go back to the PROFILES screen but the navigation bar on that screen now shows the title HOME with no back button. In other words, it appears that IOS 8 has popped the ViewController once to go back from DETAIL to PROFILES, but has somehow popped the navigation bar items twice!

Any idea how I can fix this?

Comment: you may want to include which mechanisms you are using to push onto the navigation stack. Do you use a storyboard? Are you using segues? Are you using pushViewController:? Also, do your logs mention anything about a corrupt navigation stack?

Comment: I'm just using the old standard pushViewController. I don't use storyboard or segues. This is really basic IOS coding that works fine in older version of IOS and XCode but seems to be broken in IOS8 using XCode 6.

Comment: I'm glad I'm not the only one :-) See my solution below.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the solution outline can be found here:
[UINavigationController and UINavigationBarDelegate.ShouldPopItem() with MonoTouch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6413595/uinavigationcontroller-and-uinavigationbardelegate-shouldpopitem-with-monotouc)

In my solution, I just have all my view controllers extend CustomUINavigationController, which looks like this:

```
#import "CustomUINavigationController.h"
#import "IOSVersion.h"

@interface CustomUINavigationController ()

@end

@implementation CustomUINavigationController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    self.delegate=self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

//
// The following two methods are the key to overriding the buggy behavior in IOS 8
// The first method is from here:
// https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6413595/uinavigationcontroller-and-uinavigationbardelegate-shouldpopitem-with-monotouc
//
- (BOOL)navigationBar:(UINavigationBar *)navigationBar shouldPopItem:(UINavigationItem *)item {
    NSLog(@"Inside shouldPopItem");
    if (regularPop) {
        NSLog(@"regularPop is TRUE");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"regularPop is FALSE");
    }
    if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"8.0")) {
        if (regularPop) {
            regularPop = FALSE;
            return YES;
        }

        regularPop = TRUE;
        [self popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
        return NO;
    } else {
        return [super navigationBar:navigationBar shouldPopItem:item];
    }
}

- (UIViewController *)popViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSLog(@"Inside popViewControllerAnimated");
    if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"8.0")) {
        NSMutableArray *viewControllers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:self.viewControllers];
        int cnt=(int)[viewControllers count];
        NSLog(@"Inside popViewControllerAnimated, cnt is %d",cnt);
        UIViewController *vc=[viewControllers objectAtIndex:cnt-2];
        if (regularPop) self.desiredVC=vc;
        [self popToViewController:vc animated:animated];
        return vc;
    } else {
        return [super popViewControllerAnimated:animated];
    }

}

- (UIViewController *)manualpopViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated {
    NSLog(@"Inside manualpopViewControllerAnimated");
    if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"8.0")) {
        regularPop=TRUE;
        return [self popViewControllerAnimated:animated];
    } else {
        return [super popViewControllerAnimated:animated];
    }
}

- (void)navigationController:(UINavigationController *)navigationController
   didShowViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController
                animated:(BOOL)animated {
    NSLog(@"Inside didShowViewController");
    if (viewController==self.desiredVC) {
        NSLog(@"Inside didShowViewController, found desiredVC");
        regularPop = FALSE;
    }
}

/*
#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}
*/

@end
```

Comment: Hi Marc, what is "IOSVersion.h"? Is that another custom class of yours?

Comment: Yes that's just a file I use that has macros like SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"8.0"). You can certainly infer from the name what they do. For example: #define SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(v)     ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedDescending)